# limit exposed filter to top X taxonomy terms in drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

basically I have an exposed filter that lets users use the filter to search the website.

Only the terms available are sometimes 20+ items so I want to limit the available exposed terms and show only the top X terms with the most related nodes and create a 'more' button to show the rest.

Is there already a module or something for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest I have seen to doing what you ask is http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters which tries to at least make the exposed filters more manageable.

EDIT:

If you are prepared to switch the filtering to faceted search you could use search_api module in combination with its built in facets (through solr). Then you end up with being able to restrict the amount of terms you show in the facet.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. although I agree that bef is really helpful in managing exposed filters and making them more usable for the end user, bef does not include any such function that I'm looking for.

Comment: Added an edit which may be a solution.

Comment: wow search api rules! It takes some time to configure but when I got it working... :)

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18229/how-do-i-control-the-available-options-for-an-exposed-filter) a few weeks ago and got some really good answers after using a bounty. But I haven't implemented it yet.